# Should I prefer concurrent collections over traditional collections per thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I was basically trying to insert some items (around 100000 instances of T) to a `static List<T>`(Common.VariablesList) over the method calls such as

```
a.SomeMethoad(); b.SomeMethod; c.SomeMethod; d.SomeMethod();
```

a, b, c & d inherited from a common abstract class. I added an instance property `VariablesList<T>` to their parent abstract class and started inserting items to the instance list instead of common list, so that I could use Parallel.Invoke for invoking those methods in parallel.
After the `Parallel.Invoke`, I just added all those lists to Common.VariableList.

```
Common.VariableList.AddRange(a.VariableList);
Common.VariableList.AddRange(b.VariableList);
Common.VariableList.AddRange(c.VariableList);
Common.VariableList.AddRange(d.VariableList);
```

I have recently read about concurrent collections such as `ConcurrentBag<T>`, Should I change my code to use concurrent collections or keep the implementation as it is? I mean which one is more favored in best practices of programming?

Comment: List is not thread-safe, but you shouldn't have concurrency issues when adding items to a list. You would run into trouble when editing and reading that list.

Comment: ok maybe, because I had list and dictionaries both, I was getting the problem with dictionary and I generalized that I will get the problem with other collections too, so I moved everything in the abstract class.

Comment: Yes, you will have issues adding items to a Dictionary.

Comment: @hardkoded `you shouldn't have concurrency issues when adding items to a list` I don't think that's correct. Reading is ok, but manipulating the list (especially adding) causes danger

Comment: You have to do *something*, List is not thread-safe so you can't just blindly parallelize the code.  ConcurrentBag is safe, but it doesn't behave like a list at all, it is not an ordered collection.  One of the bigger reasons why it could easily be made safe, keeping order requires synchronization.  The correct choice entirely depends on how exactly you use the collection, you can't get good advice if you don't tell us.

Comment: see also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yXtZ8x7TXw

Comment: If you don't want to go into trouble of redesigning your code using another data structure then you can just use locks whenever you're adding an item to the list. but if you want the items to be added concurrently (not sequentially) then feel free to exploit the concurrency namespace

Comment: @Bizhan I though locks may reduce performance so I just kept a list per instance and then joined them to the common list, when needed.

Comment: @HansPassant Basically I am keeping all collections (list, dictionaries)  per instance and I am not using any multithreading inside SomeMethod, so it should be thread safe.

Comment: @Deepak: in that case you only need a lock when joining the instance lists to the common list. That should limit the perfomance impact of the locks.
Anyway: you need some synchronisation mechanism when concurrently adding items to the common List. Those will always have some impact on performance .

Comment: @JohanDonne I am joining the instancelist to commonlist after Parallel.Invoke.

Comment: @Deepak: if you do that sequentially, then there will be no synchronisation issues and your code seems OK to me.

Comment: `which one is more favored in best practices of programming`? definitely **not re-inventing the wheel**. So go with concurrent bag. but It depends on the context.

Comment: @Bizhan ok. I will change the code with concurrent collections, and hope they are not slower than the current "double addition" implementation.

Comment: the code may run slower or not. But it will be in favor of the best practices.

Comment: @Bizhan I disagree... I thought my approach is somewhat favoring  "Separation of concerns". May be my question is not well understood by the community.

Comment: I don't think separation of concerns is favored here if not opposed. The concern is **one** collection of T and your approach makes that into 4 different objects which increases the code complexity and decreases the maintainability and habitability. But it all depends on the context. It's more a matter of opinions given the current context

Comment: What do you mean when you say "use parallel invoke for those methods".  Do you mean that you want to use Parallel.Invoke to call the methods 
 (i.e.: to call `a.SomeMethod()` and `b.SomeMethod()` concurrently)  Or do you mean that within the body of SomeMethod, you want to call Parallel.Invoke to do some other work?  Assuming you mean the first thing, then having each thread (a, b, c, d) have its own data as you do is *way* better in terms of performance than having either a lock or a thread-safe collection. (I can expand on this if you confirm that's what you meant.)

Comment: @Wyck yes I meant the first thing.

Comment: @Bizhan  okay, but there may be a requirement in future that user wants to filter the list based upon type. My question was more like "Should we try to minimize the use of concurrent collections in multi threaded environment by keeping a separate copy of them per thread wherever it is possible ?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So assuming each `SomeMethod` operates on a distinct object with its own data, there is no danger in calling 4 of them concurrently using Parallel.Invoke.  You don't need to do any synchronization, marshalling or locking.  This is like telling 4 bakers to each bake 1 cake, each with their own separate ingredients, utensils and ovens.  They can work completely independently.

By making the collection inside `SomeMethod` a synchronized (concurrent / thread-safe) collection, you are actually introducing overhead to protect yourself from a situation that will never occur.  Each baker must now, before touching any of their tools or ingredients, ask "is anyone else using my spoon?" and to declare "I'm using my spoon!" and to declare "I'm no longer using my spoon".  When in actual fact, there are 4 spoons, and nobody else is going to touch your spoon or your cake mix or your oven.  So just work away without synchronization.

Continuing with the analogy, let's say the idea is to get each baker to bake one layer of a 4-layer cake, then when they're all done a fifth baker will assemble all 4 layers into a final cake.

In this situation, you are the fifth baker, and you run the show.

You direct the 4 other bakers to each bake their cakes.  You do this by calling Parallel.Invoke with `a.SomeMethod()`, `b.SomeMethod()`, `c.SomeMethod()`, and `d.SomeMethod` in parallel.  When this method completes, you know that "all four cakes are ready".  At this point you do the remaining work of stacking up the cakes into a single layer cake.  You call:

```
Common.VariableList.AddRange(a.VariableList);
Common.VariableList.AddRange(b.VariableList);
Common.VariableList.AddRange(c.VariableList);
Common.VariableList.AddRange(d.VariableList);
```

Here's a full example of what I mean:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Baker
{
    List<string> myList = new List<string>();

    public string Bake(string flavor)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            myList.Add(flavor); // free to modify local data without synchronization
        }
        return string.Join("", myList);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static string Icing(string layer)
    {
        return new string('~', layer.Length) + Environment.NewLine + layer + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Baker a = new Baker();
        Baker b = new Baker();
        Baker c = new Baker();
        Baker d = new Baker();

        string cake_a = null;
        string cake_b = null;
        string cake_c = null;
        string cake_d = null;

        Parallel.Invoke(
            () => { cake_a = a.Bake("*cherry*"); },
            () => { cake_b = b.Bake("*orange*"); },
            () => { cake_c = c.Bake("*banana*"); },
            () => { cake_d = d.Bake("*choco**"); }
            );
        string layer_cake = Icing(cake_a) + Icing(cake_b) + Icing(cake_c) + Icing(cake_d);

        Console.WriteLine(layer_cake);
    }
}
```

So hopefully this illustrates that it is better to use a non-synchronized collection per object to keep overhead low (no need to talk to the other bakers because they aren't using your stuff) and just rely on how Parallel.Invoke synchronizes internally to let you know know when all the tasks are complete.  And conduct the merging operation in yet another thread (could be a fifth worker thread, or just the main thread, depending on what else is going on in your program.)